# vuex do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

[vuex] do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers.

When trying to edit the fields this message is shown in the terminal.

How do I use the form correctly?

```
<q-editor v-model="form.email" min-height="5rem" />
```

-

```
  data() {
    return {
      form: {
        email: null
      }
    };
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters('auth', ['getSeller'])
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapActions('auth', ['setSeller'])
  },
  created() {
    this.form.email = this.getSeller.email;
  }
```

--

```
vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:619 [Vue warn]: Error in callback for watcher "function () { return this._data.$$state }": "Error: [vuex] do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers."
```

UPDATE:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <q-toggle v-model="FormState.email" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  computed: {
    FormState: {
      get () {
        return this.$store.state.form
      },
      set (val) {
        this.$store.commit('auth/setSeller', val)
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

shows the same error

> Error: [vuex] do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation
>   handlers.

Comment: Can you show your `watch` functions?

Comment: I do not use...

Comment: In `created` hook, you are assigning `this.form.email` to `this.getSeller.email` (which could be a link to an object in state), thus when you change `this.form.email` you automatically change `state`.

Comment: What should I do?

Comment: First off you should create a `mutation`, if you share code of your `store` it would be nice.

Comment: What data type is `getSeller.email`? If it is an object, what properties does it have?

Comment: Since the [`q-editor` model](https://quasar.dev/vue-components/editor#QEditor-API) is a string, I doubt the error is coming from the code in your question. Can you show the stacktrace of the warning? It should come back to something in your code

Comment: Update the post

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that your `v-model` is operating directly on `this.$store.state.form.email` but your computed *getter* only deals with the `this.$store.state.form` object.

Your computed getter / setter should only work on a single property if used with `v-model`.

For example

```html
<q-toggle v-model="formEmail" />
```

```js
computed: {
  formEmail: {
    get () {
      return this.$store.state.form.email
    },
    set (val) {
      // assuming this mutates the form.email state somewhere
      this.$store.commit('auth/setSeller', val)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for listening. Should I do this in every field?

Comment: @marcelo.delta that's a very broad question. It entirely depends on how and when you want to update the state of your application.

Comment: It's up to you. My general advice though is that you should not use a state property in `v-model` unless it has a computed getter and setter. There are other options you could use but like I said, that's a pretty broad question

Comment: Is it necessary to create a get and set for each field?

Comment: Again, if you want to use them directly with `v-model`, then yes

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

```html
<template>
  <q-editor 
    :value="getSeller"  
    min-height="5rem" 
    @input="value => setSeller(value)" />
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        form: {
          email: null
        }
      };
    },
    computed: {
      ...mapGetters('auth', ['getSeller'])
    },
    methods: {
      ...mapActions('auth', ['setSeller'])
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: To more one fields?