# Error: "[vuex] do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers."

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vuex, quasar-framework

**Little Background Story**
I know this is some common error, I have looked over StackOverflow and I can't seem to find a similiar problem to mine. *I mean technically there is with the same title, BUT IT DOESN'T SOLVE MY PROBLEM.*

The following issue **is not the same** as my problem, [vuex do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57139270/vuex-do-not-mutate-vuex-store-state-outside-mutation-handlers)

I have read Vuex documentation how it's related to [vue's reactivity](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html#mutations-follow-vue-s-reactivity-rules), but it seems it's not working. I had no idea whether this is a problem with Vuex or Quasar. I have been troubling with this for a while, it seems like I missed something simple yet unknown to me.

I have the following component file named `RouteTabs.vue`, using [QTabs from Quasar](https://quasar.dev/vue-components/tabs#Example--Basic)

```
<template>
  <q-tabs
    :value="tabName"
    @input="SET_TABNAME"
    dense
    no-caps
    inline-label
    indicator-color="white"
    class="bg-blue-10 text-light-blue-2 shadow-2"
  >
    <q-route-tab
      v-for="tab in tabs"
      :key="tab.label"
      :name="tab.name"
      :icon="tab.icon"
      :label="tab.label"
      :to="tab.to"
    />
  </q-tabs>
</template>

<script>
import { mapGetters, mapMutations } from 'vuex'

export default {
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters('pages/Dashboard', [
      'tabs',
      'tabName'
    ])
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapMutations('pages/Dashboard', [
      'SET_TABNAME'
    ])
  }
}
</script>
```

And my modules named `pages/Dashboard`

```
const state = {
  tabs: [
    { name: 'vehicles', icon: 'time_to_leave', label: 'Vehicles', to: { name: 'dashboard/vehicles' } },
    { name: 'payments', icon: 'account_balance_wallet', label: 'Payments', to: { name: 'dashboard/payments' } },
    { name: 'guests', icon: 'emoji_people', label: 'Guests', to: { name: 'dashboard/guests' } }
  ],
  tabName: 'vehicles'
}

const getters = {
  tabs: state => state.tabs,
  tabName: state => state.tabName
}

const mutations = {
  'SET_TABNAME' (state, tabName) {
    state.tabName = tabName
    // ^ This updates the store successfully,
    // however the error came out same as the title
    // Vue.set(state, 'tabName', tabName) // Same as above
    // state = { ...state, tabName } // This isn't AND IT DOESN'T UPDATE
  }
}
```

If you need more information, please do ask. I will gladly provide it.
Thank you.